# Angular form name is passed as string when passed as parameter

Tags: angularjs

I'm simply trying to reset a form using the angular functions **$setPristine** & **$setUntouched** (several forms are created with ng-repeat).
 
I assign the form name dynamically by using the syntax **{{ someName }}** (the name is build on the server side and is passed as json (string)).
 
The name of the form is correctly assigned in the markup and validations are working as expected. The problem arrises when I pass that name as a parameter in the ng-click="reset(someName)" function.
 
When debugging the name comes as a string and not as the form object which causes the error. I did a quick test by hard-coding the name and pass that same name and it works fine.
My assumption is, the name coming from json is a string and the type is forwarded to the function as is, instead of the object.
 
So the question is: is there a way to convert that name so it is interpretated correctly by the controller. Or maybe there is something else I'm missing...

Here is the markup ( notice the name of the form uses {{ resto.contactForm }} ):

```
<form novalidate name="{{ resto.contactForm }}" ng-submit="submit(restoContact, resto.contactForm.$valid)" class="sky-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox state-success">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="restoContact.sameAsUser" name="sameAsUser" id="sameAsUser" value="true" ng-click="contactAutoFill()"><i></i>Contact name is same as current user.
      <input type="hidden" name="sameAsUser" value="false" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="contactName">Contact Name</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="restoContact.contactName" name="contactName" id="contactName" placeholder="John, Doe" class="form-control" required />
       <div ng-show="{{ resto.contactForm }}.contactName.$error.required && !{{ resto.contactForm }}.contactName.$pristine" class="note note-error">Please enter a name or check the box 'Same as current user'.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="contactPhoneNumber">Contact Phone Number</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="restoContact.contactPhoneNumber" name="contactPhoneNumber" id="contactPhoneNumber" placeholder="+1 555-1234-567" class="form-control" required ng-pattern="phoneNumberPattern" />
       <div ng-show="({{ resto.contactForm }}.contactPhoneNumber.$error.required || {{ resto.contactForm }}.contactPhoneNumber.$error.pattern) && !{{ resto.contactForm }}.contactPhoneNumber.$pristine" class="note note-error">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-leftM19">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset(resto.contactForm)">Cancel </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the reset function in the controller (form comes as "contactForm1" which is the correct name but is a string and not the object):

```
$scope.reset = function (form) {            
        if (form) {
            form.$setPristine();
            form.$setUntouched();
        }
        //$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
```

I have not implemented th submit method but I'm sure I will be running into the same issue.
Any suggestions or advices are welcome.
Thanks in advance...

Here is the fidle.js. the variable data is an exact response from the server.
[http://jsfiddle.net/bouchepat/v0mtbxep/]

**SOLUTION**:
http://jsfiddle.net/bouchepat/v0mtbxep/3/

I removed $setUntouched as it throws an error.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr or fiddle for this?

Comment: do you really need to dynamically name the form? In the end it is somewhat arbitrary and not really tied into the `ng-model`s directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically name a `<form>` or `<ng-form>`.

Although what you want, is make the form usable in the controller. You could do the following:

```
// in controller
$scope.form = {};
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.form.contact.$setPristine();
    $scope.form.contact.$setUntouched();
};

// in html
<form name="form.contact">
```

Comment: I found a solution that uses your suggestion, here is a fiddle of the working solution: 

http://jsfiddle.net/bouchepat/v0mtbxep/3/

I had to remove the $scope.form = {}; from controller, since I have multiple form with same name, it would just reset all the forms, so I'm still passing it as parameter:
    `$scope.reset = function (form, index) {
                if (form) {
                    form.$setPristine();
                    console.log(origData.restaurants[index]);
                    $scope.restos[index] = angular.copy(origData.restaurants[index]);
                }
            };`

Comment: @bouchepat but in this case, `form.$setUntouched();` in your `reset()` function is irrelevant; you're just saving the old data to a variable via `angular.copy()` and then restoring it via `reset()`. Glad it worked for you though.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because resto.contactForm *is* a string defined on the scope. The angular directive for form is just creating a variable on the scope with the same name. To get the variable by a string, use $eval. This should work:

```
$scope.reset = function (formName) {            
    var form = $scope.$eval(formName);

    if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
    }
    //$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
};
```

Comment: I tried that but the variable form is undefined.
formName is coming as "contactForm1" the string name of the form. I have found a solution, using zwacky suggestion, I will attach a fiddle of working solution.